# Ошибка при итерации по списку Python

Tags: python

У вас на столе лежат камни, размещенные в ряд. Каждый из них может быть красным, зеленым или синим и представлен символом R, G или B соответственно.
Помоги найти минимальное количество камней, которые он должен убрать со стола, чтобы после этого каждая пара лежащих рядом камней содержала камни разного цвета.

Вот код функции (выдает ошибку list index out of range, хотя указываю длинна списка -1):

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    spisok = []
    len_spisok = len(spisok)
    new_spisok = []
    len_new_spisok = len(new_spisok)
    for i in stones:
        spisok.append(i)
    for i in (0, len(spisok)-1):
        if spisok[i+1] == spisok[i]:
            new_spisok.append(spisok[i])
    return len_new_spisok - len_spisok


print(color_stones("RRGB"))  # == 1 # "R" убираем, остается "RGB"
print(color_stones("RRGGB"))  # == 2 # "R" и "G" убираем, остается "RGB"
print(color_stones("RRRRGB"))  # == 3 # "RRR" убираем, остается "RGB"
print(color_stones("RGBRGBRGGB"))  # == 1 # "G" убираем, остается "RGBRGBRGB"
print(color_stones("RGGRGBBRGRR"))  # == 3 # "G", "B" и "R" убираем, остается "RGRGBRGR"
print(color_stones("RRRRGGGGBBBB"))  # == 9 # "RRR", "GGG" и "BBB" убираем, остается "RGB"
```

Comment: вы забыли `range`... `for i in range(0, len(spisok)-1):`

Comment: Блин точно, спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое впечатление:

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    spisok = []
    len_spisok = len(spisok)              # всегда ноль, перенести --
    new_spisok = []                       #                          |
    len_new_spisok = len(new_spisok)      # всегда ноль, перенести --+--
    for i in stones:                      #                          |  |
        spisok.append(i)                  #                          |  |
                                          # <------------------------   |
    for i in (0, len(spisok)-1):          # пропущен range              |
        if spisok[i+1] == spisok[i]:      #                             |
            new_spisok.append(spisok[i])  #                             |
                                          # <---------------------------
    return len_new_spisok - len_spisok    # не разница, а len_new_spisok
```

Рабочий код и новые замечания:

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    spisok = []
    new_spisok = []                       # используется только длина
    for i in stones:
        spisok.append(i)                  # совпадает со stones
    len_spisok = len(spisok)              # не используется
    for i in range(0, len(spisok)-1):     # ноль можно опустить
        if spisok[i+1] == spisok[i]:
            new_spisok.append(spisok[i])
    len_new_spisok = len(new_spisok)
    return len_new_spisok
```

Окончательный код:

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    len_new_spisok = 0
    for i in range(len(stones) - 1):
        if stones[i + 1] == stones[i]:
            len_new_spisok += 1
    return len_new_spisok
```

Явное использование индексов может при вести к ошибкам. Лучше без них:

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    it = iter(stones)
    next(it, None)
    c = 0
    for a, b in zip(stones, it):
        if a == b:
            c += 1
    return c
```

Да и счётчики явные тоже код не красят:

```
def color_stones(stones: str):
    it = iter(stones)
    next(it, None)
    return sum(1 for a, b in zip(stones, it) if a == b)
    # кто не боится приведений bool -> int пишут так:
    # return sum(a == b for a, b in zip(stones, it))
```

Другой подход к решению задачи. Разберитесь сами как это работает - будет интересно:

```
import itertools


def color_stones(stones: str):
    return len(stones) - sum(1 for _ in itertools.groupby(stones))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, можете помочь вот с этим заданием: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488493/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be